# ¿Es posible transferir número de visitas en Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Yo estoy re-estructurando algunas URL de mi sitio, haciéndolas *amigables*. Por ejemplo, antes tenía una URL así:

- `www.mi-dominio.com/seccion.html`

Ahora he creado una URL *amigable*, que no usa la extensión del archivo. A lo que antes era:  `www.mi-dominio.com/seccion.html`, ahora se accede de este modo:  `www.mi-dominio.com/seccion`.

En cada una de esas páginas yo muestro la cantidad de visitas leyendo los datos desde Google Analytics. En algunos casos, las URLs tienen varios miles de visitas, los cuales como es evidente no se muestran en la nueva URL, ya que para GA se trata de algo totalmente nuevo.

Lo que quiero saber es si, dado que se trata del mismo contenido, habría alguna forma en Google Analytics, de transferir los datos de visitas a la URL antigua a la nueva. O sea, si en  `www.mi-dominio.com/seccion.html`  tenía `10,000` visitas, transferir esa cantidad de vistas a `www.mi-dominio.com/seccion`. ¿Saben si esto es posible y cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según las respuestas a una [pregunta parecida en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21351113/3695983), no se puede transferir/mapear las URLs viejas a las nuevas desde el panel de Google Analytics.

Lo que podrías hacer es usar [`trackpageview`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview) para que indicar la ruta de la página que quieres conservas los datos, y con ello apuntar a la URL vieja en lugar de a la nueva. Por ejemplo, en la página www.mi-dominio.com/seccion se haría así:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/seccion.html']);
```

De ese modo, las estadísticas para la URL nueva (www.mi-dominio.com/seccion) se seguirían mostrando con el nombre de la ruta anterior (www.mi-dominio.com/seccion.html)... lo cual, aunque conveniente para informar, puede no ser exactamente lo que quieres.

Comment: En ese caso yo preferiría hacerlo al revés, o sea, tomar las visitas de `seccion.html`, para sumarlas a las de `seccion` y presentar como número de visitas el resultado de esa suma.